# iterate over pandas.DataFrame with MultiIndex by index names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to iterate over a DataFrame with MultiIndex while using names to access a specific value of the index column. For example, given the following

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), range(3)], names=['index_a', 'index_b'])
table = pd.DataFrame({'my_column': range(len(index))}, index=index)
```

I would like to iterate over rows of `table` using a code like:

```
for row in named_index_iterator(table):
    print(row.my_column, row.index_a, row.index_b)
```

or

```
for row in named_index_iterator(table):
    print(row.my_column, row.Index.index_a, row.Index.index_b)
```

To implement `named_index_iterator` I cannot use itertuples or iterrows in `DataFrame` as that gives plain tuples, not named tuples, for the index. Similarly I cannot use something like:

```
for data_row, index_row: itertools.zip_longest(table.itertuples(), table.index):
```

as the iterator over table.index gives again plain tuples, not named tuples.

As a workaround for now I use

```
for row in table.reset_index().itertuples():
```

but that copies the table.

Comment: I understand what you're asking. I don't believe the pandas API currently supports explicit named tuples for MultiIndices. Your only option is to reset the index. Is your data frame very large?

Comment: what's wrong with `for row in df.itertuples():\n    index_a, index_b = row.Index \n ...`? or `index={k, v for k, v in zip(df.index.names, row.Index}`

Comment: @COLDSPEED - the data is not that large to avoid copy, I just thought that I missed something in MultiIndex API as accessing by name seemed for me rather basic.

Comment: @MaartenFabré - the first one hardcodes the position of index columns that I wanted to avoid using names (in real code I will use 5 or more columns), the second one is similar to what I have initially as a workaround before discovering reset_index trick that I could afford.

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question for references.

I created the following utility to iterate over indexes by names:

```
import collections

def df_iter_with_index_names(table):
    IndexNames = collections.namedtuple('IndexNames', table.index.names)
    for row in table.itertuples():
        yield (IndexNames(*row.Index), row)
```

with a usage like:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), range(3)], names=['index_a', 'index_b'])
table = pd.DataFrame({'my_column': range(len(index))}, index=index)
print(table)

def df_iter_with_index_names(table):
    IndexNames = collections.namedtuple('IndexNames', table.index.names)
    for row in table.itertuples():
        yield (IndexNames(*row.Index), row)

for index, row in df_iter_with_index_names(table):
    print(index.index_a, row.my_column)
```

It can be improved to remove the Index name from the row tuple, a leftover from `DataFrame.itertuples()`, but I can live with that.